# NotificationCenter or Closure?

Tags: swift, closures, nsnotificationcenter

> For the supervisors: I have searched a lot before I decided to ask
>   this question but I didn't find exactly what I want.

**My question is:** Which is better between using `NotificationCenter` and using `Closures` to communicate between two instances?
If they are similar, what should I use?

Hopefully, this example helps you to understand better:-

If we take `URLSession` class as an example. Why do most of its methods have a closure? Why do not they send a notification with `Data, Response, and Error` inside it?

**I know the difference between them,** I just don't know in what situations should I use each one.

Comment: Do you mean callback as oppose to closure?

Comment: @RyanH. What I mean is: When or in what situations should I use notification center (posting and observing notifications) if I can always achieve the same result by using closures.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In some cases the patterns are interchangeable, however:

1. Using a closure is the simplest solution for simple cases
2. Using a delegate is common when there is complex communication between two objects. One delegate can be better than many closures.
3. You have to use notifications when you have multiple observers or when you are not sure what objects will be observing.

You might be asking yourself why we are using closures for simple cases and not delegates or notifications. The answer is that closures are the most lightweight. They are easy to create and they positively affect your code quality.

Let's consider a completion callback. If you decide to use a notification, you need another method that will handle that notification. The same is valid for delegates. If you need some context (e.g. the parameters that triggered the actions), you will need to save it into a property.

On the other hand, a closure can be created inline. That means that **the code that triggers the action and handles its result is at one place**. This really simplifies the structure of your code. Also note that if the closure needs some context, it can capture it, without the need to create an additional property.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. Can you please explain more about what you mean by "simple cases" and "complex communication"?

Comment: @3li A simple case is a completion callback (that is, the information sent to the observer is simple - e.g. a result object and it is called only once). If you look at `UITableView` delegates, you will see an example of complex communication. You have 20 callbacks that can be called multiple times (e.g. `didSelect`). Doing that using multiple closures would be very very complicated. Not impossible, just complicated. Closures are lightweight, the easiest to use but once the interaction between objects becomes too complicated, then delegation is the answer.

Comment: Aha, I get it now. Thank you so much! ❤️

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

1. Closure is for when you want a parent to react to a child. It can be tricky to prevent retain cycle but if done right it avoid needing to use instance variables or use of `self`, e.g. when something is used in multiple closures being declared inline the closures will retain the thing as long as needed, saving you from needing to use `deinit`.
2. Notification is loose coupling for a child to react to a parent. E.g. with `UIViewControllerShowDetailTargetDidChangeNotification` you can just listen within your child view controller which saves the parent from needing to manage a list of children to notify, which is tricky if the children are changing.
3. Delegate is to customise an object without subclassing, e.g. a class that conforms to `UIApplicationDelegate` has less risk of messing up `UIApplication`'s standard behaviour like a subclass would (e.g. you forgot to call super or accidentally overrode a method with same name). It's best to have one delegate instance per target instance, e.g. don't make one instance be the delegate of multiple table views.